# Presto filter json array

Tags: presto

How can you filter a json array in Presto?

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (JSON '{"turnovers": [{"purpose": "Bla Bla", "amount": 3, "tag": "E"}, 
                          {"purpose": "Blub", "amount": 3, "tag": "F"}]}'),
    (JSON '{"turnovers": [{"purpose": "Palim", "amount": 3, "tag": "E"}, 
                          {"purpose": "Palim Palim", "amount": 3, "tag": "E"}]}')
  ) AS t (snapshot)
)
SELECT 
    json_extract(snapshot, '$.turnovers')
FROM 
    dataset
```

I would like to get only turnovers with tag `E` and not all transactions. In this example, the one transaction with tag `F` shall be excluded.

Is this even possible?

I was hoping to use sth like this, but this is not working

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (JSON '{"turnovers": [{"purpose": "Bla Bla", "amount": 3, "tag": "E"}, 
                          {"purpose": "Blub", "amount": 3, "tag": "F"}]}'),
    (JSON '{"turnovers": [{"purpose": "Palim", "amount": 3, "tag": "E"}, 
                          {"purpose": "Palim Palim", "amount": 3, "tag": "E"}]}')
  ) AS t (snapshot)
)
SELECT 
    filter(json_extract(snapshot, '$.turnovers'), x -> json_extract_scalar(x, '$.tag')='E')
FROM 
    dataset
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using json path with expression `json_extract(snapshot, '$.turnovers[?(@.tag == "E")]')` but if it fails for you as it does for me - transform data to array of rows and filter those arrays:

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (JSON '{"turnovers": [{"purpose": "Bla Bla", "amount": 3, "tag": "E"},
                          {"purpose": "Blub", "amount": 3, "tag": "F"}]}'),
    (JSON '{"turnovers": [{"purpose": "Palim", "amount": 3, "tag": "E"},
                          {"purpose": "Palim Palim", "amount": 3, "tag": "E"}]}')
  ) AS t (snapshot)
)
SELECT
    filter(CAST(json_extract(snapshot, '$.turnovers') as ARRAY(ROW(purpose VARCHAR, amount INTEGER, tag VARCHAR))), x -> x.tag = 'E')
FROM
    dataset
```

Optionally you can cast back to json if needed after filtering.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, this gives me `Final query status: FAILED - Reason: INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Cannot cast JSON to array(row(purpose varchar,amount integer,tag varchar))`. I am running this in Athena.

Comment: @PalimPalim the query in answer worked fine for me yesterday in Athena. I will check again later.

Comment: @PalimPalim the query works just fine for me in Athena. Are you executing it against real data? Possibly json structure differs?

Comment: No, I am copying as is and directly running it there. Maybe my version of aws athena is older than yours or similar, but I found a different way (a bit uglier) which works for me. See other answer here.

Comment: @PalimPalim yes, I tried that also, `as ARRAY(MAP(VARCHAR, VARCHAR))), x -> x['tag'] = 'E'` worked for me (though it turns everything into string).

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me. `ARRAY(MAP(VARCHAR, JSON))` is quite flexible and will allow also nested jsons in the json array.

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (JSON '{"turnovers": [{"purpose": "Bla Bla", "amount": 3, "tag": "E"},
                          {"purpose": "Blub", "amount": 3, "tag": "F"}]}'),
    (JSON '{"turnovers": [{"purpose": "Palim", "amount": 3, "tag": "E"},
                          {"purpose": "Palim Palim", "amount": 3, "tag": "E"}]}')
  ) AS t (snapshot)
)
SELECT
    CAST(filter(CAST(json_extract(snapshot, '$.turnovers') AS ARRAY(MAP(VARCHAR, JSON))), x -> json_format(x['tag']) = '"E"') AS JSON)
FROM
    dataset
```

Comment: You try can to prettify  it a little bit with `element_at(x, 'tag')` -> `x['tag']`. At least it works for me =) Or `x -> json_format(x['tag']) = '"E"'` can be an option instead of cast.